# How can I integrate Spring transaction management with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I've been trying to use HibernateTransactionManager to manage transactions in my service layer, but it doesn't work.
Java class configuration for creating PlatformTransactionManager:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernateConfig.properties")
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    //Other hibernate properties 

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        //Other hibernate properties removed here for brevity 

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("dataSource")
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean  sessionFactoryBean =
                new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.ldp.vigilantBean.domain");
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("sessionFactory")
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        txManager.afterPropertiesSet();

        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Later in this method call there are two calls to the persistence layer and a Runtime Exception thrown in the end. So I want these two calls to the repository to be rolled back.

```
@Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = { RuntimeException.class })
    public boolean removeCartItem(Long cartItemId) {

        Cart cart = getCartOutOfContext();

        Optional<CartItem> optCartItemToRemove =
                cart.getCartItems()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(cartItem -> cartItem.getCartItemId().equals(cartItemId))
                    .findAny();

        if (optCartItemToRemove.isPresent()) {

            CartItem cartItemToRemove = optCartItemToRemove.get();

            //There is a bug with PersistentSet in Hibernate that makes
            //using .contains() and .remove() methods of Set interface unpredictable.
            //This is a workaround: reset the whole set.
            cart.setCartItems(
                cart.getCartItems().stream()
                                   .filter(cartItem -> !cartItem.equals(cartItemToRemove))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            );

            Optional<Product> optProduct =
                    productRetrievalRepository.getProductById(cartItemToRemove.getProduct().getProductId());
            if (!optProduct.isPresent())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Specified product not found");
            Product productToRemove = optProduct.get();
            productToRemove.setUnitsInOrder(productToRemove.getUnitsInOrder() - cartItemToRemove.getQuantity());
            //First call
            productAlterRepository.updateProduct(productToRemove);

            //Second call
            cartRepository.updateCart(cart);
            if (true) throw new RuntimeException("An exception to check transactions");

            return true;
        } else
            return false;

    }
```

Repository for managing products:

```
@Repository
class ProductAlterRepositoryImpl implements ProductAlterRepository {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public ProductAlterRepositoryImpl(
            @Autowired
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

       this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Product> updateProduct(Product product) {

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

            session.getTransaction().begin();

            session.merge(product);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        return Optional.of(product);

    }
}
```

I don't understand why the changes made prior to the RuntimException thrown in my service method are not rolled back: I use the same session factory to initialize Platform Transaction Manager and to make changes via Session in my repository.
Also, I've got this line in my logger

```
*** LOG4J *** HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

If I'm right, when using only one resource (which is a Hibernate repository in my case), you don't need a Global Transaction Provider like Atomikos.
I think there suppose to be 3 transaction: one outer (the service call) and 2 inner (to repositories). The idea is that if one of the inner transactions fails it should cause the outer transaction rollback meaning all two calls to repositories would be rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside updateProduct(Product) you have opened programmatic transaction again in addition to declarative at service level. So it will ignore Spring container managed transaction manager and will use its own in isolation.
Can you please remove that and retry.

Comment: Didn't work.
I think there suppose to be 3 transaction: one outer (the service call) and 2 inner (to repositories). The idea is that if one of the inner transaction fails it should cause the outer transaction rollback meaning all two calls to repositories would be rolled back.

Comment: @Transactional at Service Implementation is enough and recommended. Please remove all programmatic transaction management stuff (begin/commit/rollback). In repository/dao level just keep code related to DB processing.

Once your line 
session.getTransaction().commit(); 
got executed it can't be rolled back

Comment: Well, it worked.
I don't know why I didn't think about grammatically managed transactions being an obstacle in here.
Thank you so much for you time and effort.